# remote: You are not allowed to upload code. while uploading code using GitLab CI Pipline

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

In GitLab CI Pipeline is responsible for release process, below is the pipeline for release stage:

```
release:
  before_script:
    - |
      git config --global user.email $GIT_USER_EMAIL
      git config --global user.name $GIT_USERNAME
      npm install -g standard-version
  stage: release
  image: node:14.15
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never                                  
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'develop'           
  script:
    - nextVersion=`npm run release -- --dry-run | grep -oP '(?<=tagging release ).*'`
    - standard-version
    - git push --follow-tags origin HEAD:$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
```

Till standard-version its working fine, but in last command getting below mentioned error :

```
remote: You are not allowed to upload code.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gitlab.com/project_name/repo_name.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the user running the pipeline have permission to perform these git actions in the remote repo? the CI-TOKEN will be that of the user running the pipeline, not of the project

Comment: How to check which user is running pipeline ? @ChrisDoyle

Comment: In the pipeline page in the UI it should show the usericon who the pipeline was ran as. You can hover over the icon to see the username

Comment: Hi @ChrisDoyle : Ok, so its my user who is running pipeline and i have permission of Maintainer, i think it should be sufficient enough to push code into repo.

Comment: Then go to `project > settings > repository > protected branches` and check that the branch you trying to push to if its protected, has `allowed push` set to at least maintainer, if its set as none that will be why you cant push.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle : At provided location i have checked and found only main branch is protected while i am trying to push code in develop branch which is not protected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248994/discussion-between-jatin-panchal-and-chris-doyle).

Comment: Yet this is unsolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem similar to yours, with a pipeline that commits to another repo. Not on gitlab.com, but on a private GitLab instance. The push command below works here.

```
git push -f https://myusername:$ACCESS_TOKEN@$CI_SERVER_HOST/$CI_PROJECT_PATH.git HEAD:${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
```

What matters for access control is the token. Any non-empty string should work as username [1]. The access token on the instance I use has write-repository scope.

There is also a CI-variable [2] in the project that contains the token. The variable brings the token into the environment where the `git push` command runs.

The idea comes from this pipeline example:
https://gitlab.com/guided-explorations/gitlab-ci-yml-tips-tricks-and-hacks/commit-to-repos-during-ci/commit-to-repos-during-ci/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

References:
[1] https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html
[2] https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#add-a-cicd-variable-to-a-project